# Trying to print something inside a try so that when one of the input is 0, it displays something

Tags: loops, try-catch, calculator

I'm trying to create a calculator with menu where user would input 1, 2, 3, 4 to choose which operation they want and #4 is the division.
I'm trying to make it so that when secondN (I'm asking for 2 inputs separated by a space at once), which is the second value is 0, it will say "You cannot divide a number by 0. Please enter another number:" and will allow user to enter two numbers again. But because dividing by zero gives infinity naturally, I'm having a hard time accomplishing this.

I have tried if and if...else inside try but I couldn't get it to work.
My code is currently as follows.

```
if(inputInt == 4){ do {
                System.out.print("Please enter two floats to divide, separated by a space:   ");
                try { firstN = readInput.nextFloat();
                     secondN = readInput.nextFloat();
                    break;  
                 } 
                catch (final InputMismatchException e) {
                    secondN = readInput.nextFloat();
                    System.out.println ("You have entered invalid value(s). Please enter valid value(s).");
                    readInput.nextLine();
                    continue;
                }
                 }while (true);
                    System.out.printf("Result of dividing %5.2f by %5.2f is %5.2f",  firstN, secondN, firstN/secondN);
                    System.out.println("\n \nPlease press enter to return to the main menu.");
                    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                    keyboard.nextLine();    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick and cheap way to add this functionality (which may be a bit unorthodox) is to check for 0 in the try-block and throw your own InputMismatchException.

```
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter two floats to divide, separated by a space:   ");
    try {
        firstN = readInput.nextFloat();
        secondN = readInput.nextFloat();
        if(secondN == 0) {
            System.out.println("The denominator cannot be 0.");
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        }
        break;
    } catch (final InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("You have entered invalid value(s). Please enter valid value(s).");
        readInput.nextLine();
    }
} while (true);
```

One thing you should also beware of is your line `secondN = readInput.nextFloat();` inside your catch-block.  It's possible that you entered the catch block because the statement `secondN = readInput.nextFloat();` in the try-block didn't work (so doing it again will throw another exception.)